# Cs50 Week1 Cash test

Tags: c, cs50

**'Im working on cs50 week 1 "cash" when i test the code the tool is working but when i submit it in the Website it's got errors and i don't know why i will add me code here'**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void){
 int changeswhithcustomer;
do{
     changeswhithcustomer = get_int("how much changes you want to exchange ? ");
}while(changeswhithcustomer < 0);
int coins = 0;
while(changeswhithcustomer >= 25){
  changeswhithcustomer = changeswhithcustomer - 25;
    coins++;
}
while(changeswhithcustomer >= 10){
  changeswhithcustomer = changeswhithcustomer - 10;
    coins++;
}
while(changeswhithcustomer >= 5){
  changeswhithcustomer = changeswhithcustomer - 5;
    coins++;
}
while(changeswhithcustomer >= 1){
  changeswhithcustomer = changeswhithcustomer - 1;
    coins++;
}
printf("%i\n",coins);
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: :( cash.c compiles
:( cash.c compiles
    code failed to compile

Comment: Don't know CS50 environment, but `#include <math.h>` is unnecessary in this program. Perhaps the Harvard boys reserve that library for when it is needed... Try removing that include statement as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Perhaps the Harvard compiler WANTS to see a `return 0;` at the end of the function. Not all compilers are wishy-washy about the presence of that return statement...

Comment: Do you mean that i have to separation the code to multiple functions?

Comment: If you are asking me, use `@fe203` so I'm notified. No, not separate functions. Just try adding `return 0;` to the end of your main()... Would help if you were more specific about "compile fails"... Edit more information into your question... Otherwise, we can only guess...

Answer (score 0):

Your program may compile but it's non-sense. Your input runs in a loop till negative which then does nothing. You use a single counts variable for each denomination but you want a variable per coin.  Here is data driven approach using a `coins` array to hold each coin's face value and count:

```
#ifdef CS50_POLYFILL
int get_int(const char *s) {
    printf("%s", s);
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    return i;
}
#else
#include <cs50.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned change(unsigned amount, unsigned face_value, unsigned *count) {
    for(*count = 0; amount >= face_value; (*count)++)
        amount -= face_value;
    return amount;
}

int main(void) {
    struct {
        unsigned face_value;
        unsigned count;
    } coins[] = {
        { .face_value = 25 },
        { .face_value = 10 },
        { .face_value = 5 },
        { .face_value = 1 },
    };
    int amount = get_int("how much changes you want to exchange? ");
    if(amount < 0)
        return 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(coins) / sizeof(*coins); i++) {
        amount = change(amount, coins[i].face_value, &coins[i].count);
        if(coins[i].count)
            printf("face value %u: count: %u\n",
                coins[i].face_value,
                coins[i].count
            );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
how much changes you want to exchange? 73
face value 25: count: 2
face value 10: count: 2
face value 1: count: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/cash/)

> **Is check50 failing to compile your code?**
>
> CS50x 2022’s version of Cash is quite different than CS50x 2021’s version. Last year’s version will fail to compile when checked by check50 (but not necessarily if you run it yourself, assuming your file consists of legal C code) due to the fact that in this new version you must implement five functions which the testing suite will test independently, beyond just checking for the final answer (as last year’s version did).

See the spec to download the correct distribution code.